# Ubuntu 12.04 Business Desktop Install file too large - 834Mb

Tags: 12.04, installation, files, iso, burning

My blank CD's are only 700 MB, and the `.iso` file I downloaded is over this. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Business Edition .iso file you downloaded with Startup Disk Creator, and make a bootable usb thumb drive version of the business edition, or burn the ISO to a DVD instead. You will more than likely need to go into your BIOS and change your boot order, or use the boot menu option (to pick a temporary boot device) if your BIOS supports it. Hope this helps!

Comment: On the right side of http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop are links to step-by-step guides for how to create a bootable USB stick with an Ubuntu CD image on Windows, OS X and Ubuntu. They should work for the Business Edition, too.

Comment: I already looked there for a solution, but I know how to create the CD, as you probably know the maximum space on blank CD is 700Mb. I had to use a 4Gb cd, and it works. Just thought the operating system install would be under 700Mb.

Comment: Nowadays a lot of OSes (Including non-Linux ones) don't even try to fit on a 700Mb CD, they assume DVDs (or USBs) for the installation media.   I've always appreciated that Ubuntu has stayed under the 700Mb cap but I find it understandable that flavors with extra features will exceed that cap.